# Printing with custom font in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

I am trying to print with a custom Barcode font.

Everything works great, as you can see below, I am printing to .pdf. The issue is that the "Test Barcode" is not displaying as barcode. When I open the .pdf the font is San Serif, but I can change it to the barcode, so the font is installed and working. The "Test Text" is displaying correctly as Times New Roman font.

I am testing in local host.

Any ideas?

```
   public void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
        pd.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);

        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Adobe PDF";       
        pd.Print();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
    }
}
void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    Font printFont = new Font("3 of 9 Barcode", 48);
    Font printFont1 = new Font("Times New Roman", 9, FontStyle.Bold);

    SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(Color.Black);

    ev.Graphics.DrawString("Test Barcode", printFont, br, 10, 65);
    ev.Graphics.DrawString("Test Text", printFont1, br, 10, 205);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the remarks from MSDN, regarding the Font constructor

```
public Font(
    string familyName,
    float emSize
)
```

> Windows Forms applications support TrueType fonts and have limited support for OpenType fonts. If the familyName parameter specifies a font that is not installed on the machine running the application or is not supported, Microsoft Sans Serif will be substituted.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/164w6x6z(v=vs.110).aspx

So I think you will probably need to double-check your font installation again.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is asp.net, not windows forms. I have looked at it time and time again, I do not know what is wrong with it.

Comment: @michaelhanon Well the remarks say WinForms but it works the same on ASP.NET applications. I think you might want to go check out the installed Fonts folder, Go To Control Panel -> Fonts, and see if your `3 of 9 Barcode` font type is in it or not. And make sure the name is exactly the same as what you specified in your code